# Display floating box search result with bulma css

Tags: css, bulma

i'm trying to display search result box using bulma, and nothing is working for me so far, i have tried bulma helpers like " is-clearfix " but it doesn't show still , i tried select and options, still doesn't display until i click, even tried honorables but couldn't get it to work, is there any way to do it using bulma css ?

my code is

starting with html:-

```
 <div class="">
    <input type="text" name="country_name" id="country_name" class="input" placeholder="Enter Country Name" />
    <div id="countryList">
    </div>
   </div>
```

Ajax part:-

```
$.ajax({
          url:"{{ route('autocomplete.fetch') }}",
          method:"POST",
          data:{query:query, _token:_token},
          success:function(data){
           $('#countryList').fadeIn();  
                    $('#countryList').html(data);
          }
         });
```

php part:-

```
$output = '<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="z-index:4000 !important; position:absolute">';
      foreach($data as $row)
      {
       $output .= '
       <li><a href="#">'.$row->name.'</a></li>
       ';
      }
      $output .= '</ul>';
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i came out with, hope this helps:-

in your controller:-

```
$output .= '
       <li><a href="'.url("manage/users").'/'. $row->id .'" class="input" style="border:2px; width:400px;">'.$row->name.'</a></li>
       ';
      }
      $output .= '</ul>';
```

and in your view:-

```
<div class="">
    <input type="text" name="country_name" id="country_name" class="input" placeholder="Enter Country Name" />
    <div id="countryList" style="position:relative; width:100px;" > 
    </div>
   </div>
```